# Edit data before visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I have my data in elasticsearch and I want to plot them using the line plot.
Currently at y-axis I have Cumulative Sum of Count and the x-axis is Aggregation of date histogram with weekly interval.

What I exactly want at y-axis is:
(some of count across all points) - (Cumulative Sum of Count)

How can I do that using Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using 'Visual Builder' visualization to achieve what you want. It has Math aggregation.

Comment: The Math aggregation is disable. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You need to first add an aggregation like sum of a field and add another aggregation to use Math aggregation. You cannot use a math aggregation without an existing aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understood your question well, but this should be straight forward using Kibana visualize - all you need to do is use Sum aggregation on the counting field, and that will allow summing all the counts in each bucket on the x-axis.

Attached a screenshot for example.

[image]